# GLUT program crashes without any exception

Tags: python, opengl, glut

I'm learning GLSL and trying write my own Ray Tracing shader. I'm using Python with PyOpenGL + GLUT. This is perfect works usually, but when I increase amount of rays to be trace program crashes on glutSwitchBuffers operation. No error messages, no exceptions in debugger, it just closes anytime app experiences highload (about 2000 ms per frame).
I can't upload my code now, so I hope anyone can give a tip or advice at least

```
from random import random
from typing import Any
from OpenGL.GL import * 
from OpenGL.GLU import * 
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
import numpy as np
import time
import win32api
from PIL import Image
import sys


class RayTracing:

    def __init__(self):

        self.start = time.time()
        self.cam_x = 0
        self.cam_y = 0
        self.cam_z = 0
        self.cam_rot_x = 0
        self.cam_rot_y = 0
        self.cam_rot_z = 0
        self.save = False
        self.samples = 25

        glutInit(sys.argv)
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB) 
        glutInitWindowSize(1920, 1080)
        glutCreateWindow(b'Ray Tracing')
        glutFullScreen()

        glutDisplayFunc(self.draw)
        glutIdleFunc(self.draw)

        with open('./rtx.frag', 'r') as shader_file:
            shader = self.create_shader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, shader_file.read())

        self.program = glCreateProgram()
        glAttachShader(self.program, shader)
        glLinkProgram(self.program)
        glUseProgram(self.program)

        self.width = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH)
        self.height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT)

        location = glGetUniformLocation(self.program,'WindowSize')
        glUniform2f(location, self.width, self.height)

        glutKeyboardFunc(self.catch_keyboard)
        glutSpecialFunc(self.specialKeys)
        glutPassiveMotionFunc(self.mouse)
        glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_NONE)
        

    def draw(self):

        location = glGetUniformLocation(self.program,'samples')
        glUniform1i(location, self.samples)

        location = glGetUniformLocation(self.program,'time')
        glUniform1f(location, self.start - time.time())

        location = glGetUniformLocation(self.program,'camera_pos')
        glUniform3f(location, self.cam_x, self.cam_y, self.cam_z)

        location = glGetUniformLocation(self.program,'camera_rot')
        glUniform3f(location, self.cam_rot_x, self.cam_rot_y, self.cam_rot_z)

        location = glGetUniformLocation(self.program,'seed_1')
        glUniform2f(location, random(), random())
        location = glGetUniformLocation(self.program,'seed_2')
        glUniform2f(location, random(), random())

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        glRecti(-1, -1, 1, 1)

        glutSwapBuffers()  # Crashes on this line

    def create_shader(self, shader_type, source):

        shader = glCreateShader(shader_type)
        glShaderSource(shader, source)
        glCompileShader(shader)
        return shader

    def catch_keyboard(self, key, x, y):
        if key == b'w':  # 87
            self.cam_x += 1
        if key == b's':  # 83
            self.cam_x -= 1
        if key == b'a':  # 65
            self.cam_y -= 1
        if key == b'd':  # 68
            self.cam_y += 1
        if key == b'e':  # 16
            self.cam_z += 1
        if key == b'q':  # 17
            self.cam_z -= 1

    def specialKeys(self, key, x, y):
        if key == GLUT_KEY_END:
            self.samples = 2500
            self.save = True
            glutHideWindow()

    def mouse(self, x, y):
        dx = 1920 / 2 - x
        dy = 1080 / 2 - y
        self.cam_rot_z += dy / 1080
        self.cam_rot_y += -dx / 1920
        win32api.SetCursorPos((int(1920 / 2), int(1080 / 2)))

    def run(self):
        glutMainLoop()

rtx = RayTracing()
rtx.run()
```

Comment: Most desktop drivers have an internal timeout. They kill each process when it takes too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I find solution by myself using [BDL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2579738/bdl) comment.
When graphic card render frame more then 2 seconds Windows just kill that process. This is called TDL timeout.
There is two way to solve an issue when you need to do hard calculations:

1. Increase TDL timeout [click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/tdr-registry-keys) (not recommend)
2. Split your sample in little ones and calculate them one by one calling glFlush or smth like that.